# Pygame. How do I catch the pressing of <pgup> and <pgdn> keys?

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason, the code below doesn't seem to work for me

```
running = True
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.K_PAGEDOWN:
            # do something
        if event.type == pygame.K_PAGEUP:
            # do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look at `event.type` to check the type of the event and then if it
is a `KEYDOWN` event you look at `event.key` to check which key
has been pressed.

So what you are looking for is something like that:

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:   
            running = False             
        elif event.type = pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_PAGEDOWN:
                # do something
            elif event.key == pygame.K_PAGEUP:
                # do something
```